# Interleave files with CMD using echo

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, interleave

How could I interleave files line by line with

### **cmd.exe**

with help of **read, grep, echo, etc**?

File1.txt with the context:

```
Aaaaaaa1 
Aaaaaaa2 
Aaaaaaa3
```

File2.txt with the context:

```
Bbbbbbb1
Bbbbbbb2
Bbbbbbb3
```

I would like to combine File1.txt and File2.txt in other file (OUTCOME.txt) in this way:

```
Aaaaaaa1
Bbbbbbb1
Aaaaaaa2
Bbbbbbb2
Aaaaaaa3
Bbbbbbb3
```

Answer (score 5):

You need a method to read from two files in parallel. This is possible by using two methods at the same time (`<file1 set /p` and `for /f ... in (file2)`):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

<file2.txt (
  for /f "delims=" %%a in (file1.txt) do (
    set /p b=
    echo %%a
    echo !b!
  )
) >outcome.txt
```

Comment: Perhaps you should mention applicable limitations like line lengths or forbidden characters -- what do you think?

Comment: I don't think that it is necessary, as long as the answer works with the information provided then it is perfectly valid as is. If it doesn't then the OP is free to edit their currently off topic question to include fuller and more accurate details.

Comment: Clever: set /p + stdin redir

Comment: [Comparison of the lines with batch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50068272/778560)