# If variable A = variable B do something in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am working on a batch file where I need to compare each line of for loop A and for loop B in order to execute another command, but I can't seem to figure this one out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  The code I have so far is listed below.

```
@echo OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('Type "%Paths%"') do (echo %%~nxA)
pause
for /f "delims=" %%B in ('Type "%Names%"') do (echo %%B)
```

Comment: Please let us know if the duplicate doesn't answer your question or when you have problems adapting it to your needs.

Comment: Stephan.  The duplicate doesn't answer my question.  From the code above, I am reading one text file and getting just the file name from the full file paths and reading a second text file listing the files names themselves.  I then need to compare those results and if they are equal, then I need to zip up the file listed in the full file path.

Comment: why not just use findstr: `For /f Delims^= %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /G:"names.txt" "paths.txt"')Do Echo(%%~nG found in %%G`

Comment: [Comparison of the lines with batch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50068272/778560)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

```
for /f "delims=" %%B in ('Type "%Names%"') do (
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('Type "%Paths%"') do (
  if "%%~nxA" == "%%B" (echo "We have a match.")
  )
)
```

Thank you for everyone's assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted the linked duplicate to your requirements (untested, because I have no exact  information about your source files)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

<"%NAMES%" (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ("%PATHS%") do (
    set /p b=
    if "%%~nxA" == "!b!" (
      echo here zip "%%A" 
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: What "linked duplicate" are you referring to?

Comment: @aschipfl - this was dupehammered with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152975/interleave-files-with-cmd-using-echo